# Highchart data parsed after ajax answer

Tags: php, json, jquery, highcharts

I received from a jquery ajax function a response like :

```
["{y:55,color:'red'}", "{y:21}", "{y:12}", "{y:6}", "{y:3}", "{y:3}"]
```

In my PHP code, I encode via json_encode in an array :

```
foreach($pp as $value){ 
$tmp[]='{y:'.round(100*$pp/$sum_pp,0).'}';
}
echo json_encode(array("tableau"=>$tmp));
```

I'd like to have this, to be used in my Highchart graph :

```
[{y:55,color:'red'}, {y:21}, {y:12}, {y:6}, {y:3}, {y:3}]
```

How do I have to format my array to graph my answer ? I do this way to be able to change color on one column in the serie.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you rephrase that? What's stored in `$pp`? You use a `foreach` on it as if it was an array but them you use it inside the cicle instead of `$value`.

Comment: $pp contains value I want to put into percentage. I made a mistake on my post. It was round(100*$value/$sum_pp,0)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to change the PHP code I would opt to output something similar to the series object used in Highcharts, see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.

That is an object which looks like this:

```
{
    data: [y1, y2, y3],
    color: '#FF0000'
}
```

That would make your PHP code look like this:

```
foreach($pp as $value){ 
    $tmp[] = round(100*$pp/$sum_pp,0);
}
echo json_encode(array(
    "data" => $tmp,
    "color" => '#FF0000'
));
```

On a side note, filling `$tmp` like you did in the question is bad. A better way would be:

```
foreach($pp as $value){ 
    $tmp[] = array('y' => round(100*$pp/$sum_pp,0)); 
} 
echo json_encode(array("data"=>$tmp));
```

As this will create a "propper" object when parsed in your Javascript. Both examples above in my code will produce something you can use directly in Highcharts. Please note that the `series` parameter takes an array of series. So in your javascript you would have to do:

```
series: [
    data: response
]
```

Where `response` is the is the the output from the `json_encode` in you PHP script.